# How do i get my size attribute values in fronend? I have created size attribute as multiselect option

Tags: magento-1.9

I want all selected size in frontend

```
$categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
$count = is_array($categories)?count($categories):$categories->count();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$sizeLabel = $product->getAttributeText('size');

<?php if ($count): ?>
    <div class="filters">
        <dl class="filters_facet-list">
            <dt>
                <?php echo $this->__('Sub Category'); ?>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <ol class="filters_option-list">
                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                        <?php if ($category->getIsActive()): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category); ?>" <?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()); ?>
                                    <span class="count"><?php echo $category->getProductCount(); ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="">
            <?php echo $sizeLabel;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not able to get Results because you do not have any product loaded.
You are using

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

This will only create an object of a product but will not get any product data.

You need to use `load` to get the product before you can get its sizes like below.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID);
```

And then use code

```
echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

It will give you a comma separated list of selected sizes for your product.

To get All Size Attribute Options, use below.

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'size');

if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
print_r($options);
```

Comment: How do i get my current product id?

Comment: @SushantThorat if you are on view page you can get it by $_product->getId();

Comment: You can use `$product = Mage::registry('current_product');` @SushantThorat

Comment: Thanks @Jaimin 
But i want all sizes display in my sidebar filter. So now i dont want only perticular products size, i want all sizes in my filter. How do i achieve?

Comment: @SushantThorat, check updated code to get all options of size attribute.

Comment: Great!! its working

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('car_options')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: thnks but its not working :(